# How to do a hard KILLED/ROLLBACK on blocking sessions

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL server agent that runs nightly first by dropping a table [table1] and then inserting a new table [table1] with refreshed data. However, the table [table1] can not be dropped because it is blocked by a session. I killed all active sessions to clear the blocking but the status is still showing as "running" after 3 days. Is there any way to do a hard KILL/ROLLBACK. After three days if the sessions are not killed or Rolledback what is the other option.

[image]

Thank you for your help
Kind Regards
Solomon

Comment: If you have a transaction that has been running for 3 days, and not completed, I would be finding out what the SQL is that it's running and fixing that. Blindly killing long running transactions doesn't solve the far bigger underlying problem.

Comment: The SQL server agent was running for many years without problem. The agent runs stored procedure step by step following one after the other. This happened when a staff member rebooted the server and the steps crushed and blocked each other . The key point is how to drop [Table1] and how to kill/rollback the blocking session from dropping [table1]

Comment: *"This happened when a staff member rebooted the server and the steps crushed and blocked each other "* If the server is rebooted then ***all*** the connections would be dropped; it would be impossible for them to block each other as they would all be implicitly rolled back. I'm smelling an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) here.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, does rebooting the SQL server now be a solution? what would be the effect if I rebooted the server now

Comment: If you rebooted the server now, then any existing connections would be closed, and any uncommitted transactions would be implicitly rolled back (as I mentioned in my prior comment).

Comment: @Solomon nuking the server every day doesn't fix the serious underlying problem. As you said, the server had been working for years without problem. Now it has a problem that needs fixing. At the very least, go to `Activity Monitor` and check what's blocking the job. `and the steps crushed and blocked each other` that doesn't make any sense - when the server reboots, there are no jobs, no blocks no sessions. `The key point is how to drop [Table1] and how to kill/rollback the blocking session from dropping [table1]` what does that mean? There are no sessions

Comment: `how to drop [Table1]` what does this job do? Does it create non-temporary tables for "temporary" use? Does it try to use them as some sort of queue? If it used temp tables, they'd be dropped automatically when the server rebooted or even when the connection was killed. The job has to try hard to result in a 3-day hang after a reboot